# SafeMySQL Access denied, как исправить?

Tags: php, mysql

Error:`Fatal error: SafeMySQL: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Error initiated in /sites/***/page.php on line 7, thrown in /sites/***/apanel/db.mysql.php on line 892`

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SafeMySQL многое делает за тебя, но угадать настройки соединения с БД она за тебя не может.

Надо получить у провайдера параметры доступа к БД и вписать их в массив при создании объекта, - как и написано в документации и в самом файле.

```
$opts = array(
    'host'    => 'localhost',
    'user'    => 'user',
    'pass'    => 'pass',
    'db'      => 'db',
);
$db = new SafeMySQL($opts);
```